# Is there any tut/e.g available to implement a u.i navigation tool similar to flipboard browser?

Tags: ios5, uisplitviewcontroller, navigationcontroller, flipboard

Does anyone knows a tutorial that could help me to build something similar to the browser of flipboard?

Basically i would like to filter some contents from a DB in my app and I am specially interested to understand how their browser was implemented as I would like:

1. To be able to have the browser to overlay the main view on the right
   side.
2. Shadow the detail view when the browser is seen
3. To have a toolbar in the main view to filter some of my data too.

I am not sure if i should go for the master / detail template or start with a simple view template.

Answer (score 0):

The feature I was looking at is easier to implement through a UIPopoverController. The popover allows to display a layer that overlay the main window and that can be dismissed when clicking outside of popover view.

Using the master/detail template was not adapted here. I started with a single view template instead.

I am still looking into some way for the customization of the UIPopoverController though.